SVG color change on focus using Tailwind
I'm creating a sidenav, i want the svg icon to change colour when its focused but not the text colour
ive created this so far but i have to reclick it again to set it back to default rather than it auto changing on new item click
const LinkWithIcon = ({ icon: Icon, text, href }) => {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);
  const handleSelect = () => {
    setIsSelected(!isSelected);
  };
  return (
    <div className="">
      <a
        className="flex items-center h-10 gap-3 rounded px-3 py-2 text-muted-foreground hover:text-foreground hover:bg-muted transition-all"
        href={href}
        onClick={handleSelect}
      >
        <Icon className={`h-4 w-4 ${isSelected ? 'text-foreground ' : ''}`} />
        {text}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

